# split flutter screen in two parts while using flutter_barcode_scanner package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using flutter_barcode_scanner package from Flutter. I'm trying to build a single screen app. One is the main screen and the other is the screen when barcode scanning starts.

What I want to do is split the screen into two parts and place barcode scanning screen at upper half and buttons of main screen on the second half. But it seems the package does not allow to make this happen (No such customization options in its API). How to do this or recommend some other barcode scanning package which gives such option.

Main screen

[image]

Once "scan barcode" button is pressed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually change the package.

Goto `.packages` file and find the package location, then edit the code to your liking. I've used other barcoding scanning packages and they also open a new screen.